# Correctly Parsing Text Within Function With Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing

I receive a set of functions in text for another software program which I need to modify and then save and am trying to find the best way to do this.

I could receive a text like this:

`Sum(Revenue) + Sum({<CostCentre={'$(=Sum(FIELD))'}>}COGS)`

I would like to be able to add text directly after `Sum(` where it is NOT immediately followed by `{<` Ideally my end result would like this:

`Sum(TEXT_I_WANT_TO_ADD Revenue) + Sum({<CostCentre={'$(=Sum(TEXT_I_WANT_TO_ADD FIELD))'}>}COGS)`

Any ideas how to achieve this in a simple way? So far my only idea was to use split and then look at the next object of the array to determine if it contains `{<`, however I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this.

My try (which works and but is hard to follow and not sure if it will always work):

```
let text = `Sum(Revenue) + Sum({<CostCentre={'$(=Sum(FIELD))'}>}COGS)`;
let input_text = 'TEXT_I_WANT_TO_ADD ';
let split_text = 'Sum('
let split = text.split(split_text);
console.log(split);
let final_text = '';
for (let i in split) {
  let split_modified;
  // Not last item
  if (i < split.length - 1) {
    let next = (parseInt(i) + parseInt(1));
    // Does not include {<
    console.log(next, split[next]);
    if (!split[next].includes('{<')) {
      final_text += split_text + input_text;
    }
    // Does include {<
    else {
      final_text += split_text + split[next]
    }
  }
  // Last item
  else {
    final_text += split[i]
  }
}
console.log(final_text);
```

Any ideas how to do this is a better, easier way?

Comment: You need to learn the grammar of that language, write a parser for it, manipulate the AST and generate code back from the AST. This is not a "simple", but the only robust way.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the `word` inside the parenthesis of `Sum()` and replace it :

```js
const input_text = "TEXT_I_WANT_TO_ADD ";
const text = `Sum(Revenue) + Sum({<CostCentre={'$(=Sum(FIELD))'}>}COGS)`;

const result = text.replace(/Sum\(\w+\)/g, match => `Sum(${input_text})`);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is a good start, however it still does not work properly. For example if my text variable looks like this then it does not pick it up:
`'Sum([UNITS IN INVENTORY]*[Cost of Goods])'`

 I also need to keep whatever text is within the Sum() text..